# Can anyone help me reduce the time-complexity of the following code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I'm new to hackerrank. I always prefer to code without going for the solution. By doing so I got this problem,as my code(given below) is getting the required output but for large inputs,it doesn't execute within the time limit. So anyone help me to reduce the time complexity. Also tell me that coding without looking for solution is good or bad...

```
long arrayManipulation(int n,int m, vector<vector<int>> q) {
    long result=0;
vector<long> arr(n,0);

for(long i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(long t=q[i][0];t<=q[i][1];t++)
    {
        arr[t-1]+=q[i][2];
    }

}

for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(result<arr[i])
    {result=arr[i];}
}

return result;
}
```

[These seven test cases aren't passing](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D3LeWFNrm9tMVuukHczmxTZdASWdklqu)

Comment: What does the code do? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: input q contains 2 dimensional array
1 3 100
2 5 100
3 4 100

first two column shows range of a new array in which third column number has to be added.

Comment: there's a method don't know what it's name, but let  `a := [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and you want to add 5 for elements of initial array from 2nd to 4th (not included) for example, then you can do `a[2] += 5`, `a[4] -= 5` and then calculate prefix sums on `a`, that will be how much you need to add to each element of your initial array (`[0, 5, 5, 0, 0]` in this case)

Comment: so I've just described how you can reduce complexity of this in your code: `for(long t=q[i][0];t<=q[i][1];t++) { arr[t-1]+=q[i][2]; }`

Comment: a[2] += 5, a[4] -= 5 will it work(this syntax)

Comment: in your syntax there's `arr[q[i][0]] += q[i][2]`, `arr[q[i][1] + 1] -= q[i][2]` and then `arr[i]` is sum of `arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[i]`

Comment: sorry bro i cant understand 

for example:
if an  array[5]  in this array 1 to 4 (including) needs to be added with 10.
can u expalin your idea with this example.

Comment: @eswardada wrote an answer

Comment: The question should be asked here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be reduced:

```cpp
vector<long> arr(n,0);
for(long i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(long t=q[i][0];t<=q[i][1];t++)
    {
        arr[t-1]+=q[i][2];
    }

}
```

to something like:

```cpp
vector<long> arr(n + 1,0);  // n+1 needed because q[i][1] can be n-1
for(long i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    arr[q[i][0]] += q[i][2];
    arr[q[i][1] + 1] -= q[i][2];
}
long sum = 0;
for(long i=0;i<m;i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    arr[i] = sum;
}
```

That works, because for example let `a := [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and you want to add 5 for elements of initial array from 2nd to 4th (not included), then you can do `a[1] += 5`, `a[3] -= 5` (`a` is `[0, 5, 0, -5, 0]`) and then calculate prefix sums on `a`, that will be how much you need to add to each element of your initial array (`[0, 5, 5, 0, 0]` in this case).